# Call method on class by method reference

Tags: javascript

I have a reference called `func` that links to a static method called `method`, and when I call `func()`, the method cannot find the static method `_open`. I am not sure why, but I assume it is because `func` is a method and I am calling it as such.

It looks something like this:

```
class A {
  static method() {
    this._open()
  }
  static _open() {
    // Do stuff
  }
}
```

I have tried to call the method like this:

```
/**
 * Finds the data in a object/array if it exists
 * `a.b.c` -> `{a: {b: {c: 'some value'}}}`
 */
function find(query, data) {
  return query.split('.').reduce((obj, val) => {
    return obj ? obj[val] : obj
  }, data)
}

// func is a reference to `method`
let func = find('A.method', {A: A})
func.constructor.prototype[func](...params)
```

However, it gives me this error:

> TypeError: func.constructor.prototype[func] is not a function

When logging `func` it looks like this:

```
console.log(func.toString())
// Output:
// method() {
//   this._open()
// }
```

How can I call a static method on a class with only the reference to the method?

Comment: Shouldn't you always be calling the static method _open by using `A._open()` instead of `this._open()`?

Comment: You don't need to since they are both static

Comment: `A.method.constructor` is `Function` not `A`. Without a reference to `A` there is nothing connecting `method` to it if you only have a reference to `method`. It doesn't "know" it's a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure that `find` returns the method, as bound to A, otherwise, when `method` is called, `this` will refer to the global `this` (`window` or undefined), and then you can just call `func()`:

```js
class A {
  static method(...args) {
    console.log('args', args);
    this._open()
  }
  static _open() {
    console.log('opening');
  }
}

const find = () => A.method.bind(A);

const func = find('method');
func('abc', 'def');
```

If you only have a reference to `func`, and not to the class A, there's no way to get to A again. Referencing `func.constructor` would only make sense if `func` was an *instance* (in which case referencing its `.constructor` would take you to `A`) - but `func` is a method of the class, not an instance of the class.

If you need to dynamically detect what the last object before the return value from `find` is, so you can bind the function if necessary, add a bit more logic to the `find` function, to get to the last object and the last key:

```js
class A {
  static method() {
    this._open()
  }
  static _open() {
    console.log('opening');
  }
}

function find(query, data) {
  const keys = query.split('.');
  const lastKey = keys.pop();
  const lastObj = keys.reduce((obj, val) => {
    return obj ? obj[val] : obj
  }, data);
  const ret =  lastObj[lastKey];
  return typeof ret === 'function' ? ret.bind(lastObj) : ret;
}

// func is a reference to `method`
let func = find('A.method', {
  A: A
});
func('param 1', 'param 2')
```

Comment: I have added what my `find` function looks like if that is an help. So I don't think I have a direct reference.

Comment: Awesome! I have got this working in my own project now!

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure, what you are doing this for:

```js
class A {
  static method() {
    return this._open(...arguments)
  }
  static _open() {
    return arguments;
    // Do stuff
  }
}
function find(classHere, method){
  return classHere[method].bind(classHere);
}
var func = find(A, 'method');
console.log(func('test', 'is', 'this', 'what', 'you', 'want'));
```